# microsoft excel add inter dependent cells

Tags: excel, cells

Is there a way to add two cells in Excel where one is calculated based on what is entered in the other? Basically something like a value and percentage field where the original base value is provided.

Example:

```
Cell 1 - Original Value
Cell 2 - Set Value amount
Cell 3 - Set Percentage
```

So if Cell 1 is preset to 1000 and Cell 2 and Cell 3 are empty.

- Entering 350 in Cell 2 calculates Cell 3 and sets it to 35%
- Entering 35% in Cell 3 calculates Cell 2 and sets it to 350

Answer (score 0):

A call can contain either a formula OR a value. If you need anything more advanced I beleive you'll have to set it up in VBA specific to your project.